# Multiple issues: Not regnizing second monitor, authentication failed & no Power Off

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, login, display, authentication

I am facing three issues with my Ubuntu 20.04 installation on a laptop

1. All a sudden my OS has stopped recognizing my second monitor connected through HDMI.
2. The following login screen appears up requesting credentials, but I do not know what caused it to appear. The password I am providing is correct but the login screen refuses to take it.

   [image: Authentication required to run /usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
3. After clicking 'Power Off', it takes 15 minutes for the confirmation screen to appear and the system won't shut down.

I wanted to know if the above three are related and how can I fix them.

Let me know if I should provide further information.

Answer (score 1):

This resolved my issue- turned off machine using `sudo shutdown now` a couple of times.